# How do I overcome the "undefined offset 0" and "undefined variable:str" notice in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined

I have an if and array statement in my PHP which is showing the notice undefined offset & undefined variable. How do I overcome those two errors in below code?

> undefined offset 0
>
> undefined variable:str

```
 function calc_pending_conf(){
$comm = array();
global $wpdb;
$unsecurearray = array();
$nps = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND comment_status = 'open'");
$numposts=0;
foreach($nps as $np){
    if (comments_open($np->ID)){
        $numposts++;
        $unsecurearray[]=$np->ID;
    }
}
$allusers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_users");
foreach ($allusers as $usr):
    $comcount=0;
    $args = array('user_id' => $usr->ID);
    $usercomment = get_comments($args);
    foreach($usercomment as $cot) :
        if(in_array($cot->comment_post_ID,$unsecurearray)){$comcount++;}
    endforeach;
    $snumposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_ps_security, wp_posts WHERE wp_ps_security.sec_protect_id = wp_posts.ID AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.comment_status = 'open'");
    $unsecure = $numposts - $snumposts;
    $cid = $usr->ID;
    $groupid = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT grel_group_id FROM wp_ps_group_relationships WHERE grel_user_id = '".$cid."'");
    if(isset($groupid) && is_array($groupid) && is_object($groupid[0])):
    if($groupid[0]->grel_group_id==11 || $groupid[0]->grel_group_id==3 || $groupid[0]->grel_group_id==1 || sizeof($groupid)==0):
        $pendingc = 0;
    else:
        $applicable=0;
        foreach($groupid as $grp){
            $str = $str."wp_ps_security.sec_access_id=".$grp->grel_group_id." OR ";
        }
        global $applicablearray;
        $applicablearray = array();
        $aarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT wp_ps_security.sec_protect_id FROM wp_posts,wp_ps_security WHERE wp_posts.comment_status='open' AND wp_posts.post_status='publish' AND wp_posts.post_type='post' AND (".substr($str, 0, -3).") AND wp_posts.ID=wp_ps_security.sec_protect_id");
        foreach ( $aarray as $aa ) 
        {
            $applicablearray[]=$aa->ID;
        }
        $applicable = sizeof($applicablearray);
        
        $pendingc = $unsecure + $applicable - $comcount;
    endif;
    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE wp_users SET confpending=".$pendingc." WHERE ID=".$cid);
    update_user_meta( $cid, 'confpending', $pendingc );
endforeach;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't use variables that are undefined?

Make use of [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to ensure that a variable exists before trying to access it.

<sub>Personally, and *do not do this yourself*, but personally I set error reporting to `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`. It's a bad idea and I say again *you should not do this*, but it is an option if you're willing to accept the risk that things will silently screw up if you mis-type a single variable name.</sub>

Comment: Well, if you mistype a variable name and it goes to production, you may prefer an error message than a silently failing code that you may notice weeks later... But at least you made it clear it was not a good idea :-)

Comment: Ideally you would notice things messing up *before* code goes to production :p

Comment: Indeed, but if you fail to notice it for some reason (ex: code may fail because of specific user input you didn't test), you really would need some kind of error logging, or at least error message. It's hard enough to have users tell when they encounter an error, if there is no error message but a silent fail, it could be much too late when you notice it and you may, for example, have inconsistant data or missing data in your database... But hey I don't want to discuss this, I've written my part of `on error resume next` a few years ago :-)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i have inserted isset condition but still showing  unexpected showing syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach'. it would be grateful if u edit the above function  to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

php checks if conditions lazily and he won't continue forward if something fails the if.

For example IF (A AND B), if A is false, B is never checked.

You can use this in your example, you can check isset($groupID[0]) AND (everything else).

if $groupID[0] isn't set, the whole if check is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Check $groupid before:

```
    // you just need insert this line before your if statement:
    if(isset($groupid) && is_array($groupid) && is_object($groupid[0]))
    // Your code
    if($groupid[0]->grel_group_id==11 || $groupid[0]->grel_group_id==3 || $groupid[0]->grel_group_id==1 || sizeof($groupid)==0):
```

Comment: Now it's showing  syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' , i'm beginner in php for better clarity i pasted the full function.

Comment: I copy-pasted foreach from your example, now I am removed it.

Comment: I tried that also it showing syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Try my solution and feel free to ask questions!

Comment: I have inserted the line as you mentioned but it still showing the same error.

Comment: Is is possible to edit above function and were should exactly insert isset, or any other command if required.